# Ruby visual debugger run from linux terminal

Tags: ruby, debugging

Is there a ruby visual debugger that i can run from the linux terminal?
And if so, how do i run it?

Comment: visual? command line? I don't think those two keywords go well together. Are you looking for a command line debugger or some kind of integrated environment with a graphical interface (IDE)? Maybe you just need [IRB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell), you need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: i can run applications from the command line, like with perl i can run "perl -dptkdb somescript.pl", from the terminal and then i get http://ptkdb.sourceforge.net/images/ptkdb-win-example1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several graphical debuggers available for Ruby, e.g [Mr. Guid](http://mr-guid.rubyforge.org/), [rudebug](http://code.google.com/p/rudebug/) or the [RubyMine IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/features/ruby_debugger.html), the latter of which does not seem to quite fit your use case. `ruby -r debug [script]` runs on the command line but is also quite usable.

Comment: mr guid it is, its not the best but it works. rudebug i had trouble installing.

Comment: had to run 'sudo apt-get install fantasdic' for mr guid though.